# Separated italic and span tags inside list element in xslt

Tags: html, xml, xslt, indesign-server

I am new in XSLT world, thank you in advance for your understending. I need to prepare a xml which will be send to Adobe InDesign server. In the html files, which are my input that I need to transform to xml and send to Adobe InDesign by using XSLT transformation, I have "li" elements that have "span" tags and "i" (italic) tags inside. I would like to treat "i" tags, to be italics in the final xml for InDesign. I tried to match "i" tags by the following xslt:

```
<xsl:template match="i" mode="process-text">
      <CharacterStyleRange AppliedCharacterStyle="CharacterStyle/Italic">
        <Content>      
           <xsl:copy-of select="text()"/>
        </Content>
    </CharacterStyleRange>
</xsl:template>
```

but without results.

For example, I have the following input:

```
<li class="MsoNormal" style="mso-list:l0 level2 lfo1;tab-stops:list 1.0in">Systolic dysfunction: an&#xa0;<i>inotropic</i>&#xa0;abnormality, due to myocardial infarction (MI) or dilated or ischemic cardiomyopathy (CM), resulting in diminished systolic emptying (ejection fraction &lt;45%).</li>
```

I would like to transform it to the following one:

```
<ParagraphStyleRange AppliedParagraphStyle="ParagraphStyle/BL2">
         <CharacterStyleRange AppliedCharacterStyle="CharacterStyle/$ID/[No character style]">
            <Content>Systolic dysfunction: an </Content>
            <CharacterStyleRange AppliedCharacterStyle="CharacterStyle/Italic">
                <Content>inotropic</Content>
            </CharacterStyleRange>
        <Content> abnormality, due to myocardial infarction (MI) or dilated or ischemic cardiomyopathy (CM), resulting in diminished systolic emptying (ejection fraction &lt;45%).</Content>
            <Br/>
         </CharacterStyleRange>
   </ParagraphStyleRange>
```

My initial problem is how to split a "li" tag and treat (separately) the text inside, and also treat separately "span" and "i" tags inside "li" by XSLT? Thank you in advance for any help.

**UPDATE:**
My main template, for "li" elements is:

```
<xsl:template match="li[not(descendant::p) and not(ancestor::section[@class='references' or @class='References'])]" mode="li-pass1">    
       <xsl:variable name="depth" select="count(ancestor::li) + 1"/>
    
    <xsl:variable name="listType">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="parent::ol">
          <xsl:value-of select="'NL'"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="'BL'"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    
      <ParagraphStyleRange AppliedParagraphStyle="ParagraphStyle/{$listType}{if ($depth eq 1) then '' else $depth}">          
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="descendant::i/text()">
          <Content>      
             <xsl:copy-of select="./text() | descendant::span/text() "/>
          </Content>
      <CharacterStyleRange AppliedCharacterStyle="CharacterStyle/Italic">
              <Content>      
                  <xsl:copy-of select="descendant::i/text()"/>
              </Content>
          </CharacterStyleRange>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <Content>      
             <xsl:copy-of select="./text() | descendant::span/text() "/>
          </Content>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
      </ParagraphStyleRange>
    </xsl:template>
```

This template affects final xml in a wrong way. I got the following result:

```
<ParagraphStyleRange AppliedParagraphStyle="ParagraphStyle/BL">
         <CharacterStyleRange AppliedCharacterStyle="CharacterStyle/$ID/[No character style]">
            <Content>Two potential pathophysiologic conditions lead to the clinical findings of HF, namely systolic and/or diastolic heart dysfunction. 
          </Content>
         </CharacterStyleRange>
         <CharacterStyleRange AppliedCharacterStyle="CharacterStyle/Italic">
            <Content>inotropiccompliance</Content>
         </CharacterStyleRange>
         <CharacterStyleRange AppliedCharacterStyle="CharacterStyle/$ID/[No character style]"/>
      </ParagraphStyleRange>
      <ParagraphStyleRange AppliedParagraphStyle="ParagraphStyle/BL2">
         <CharacterStyleRange AppliedCharacterStyle="CharacterStyle/$ID/[No character style]">
            <Content>Systolic dysfunction: an  abnormality, due to myocardial infarction (MI) or dilated or ischemic cardiomyopathy (CM), resulting in diminished systolic emptying (ejection fraction &lt;45%).</Content>
         </CharacterStyleRange>
         <CharacterStyleRange AppliedCharacterStyle="CharacterStyle/Italic">
            <Content>inotropic</Content>
         </CharacterStyleRange>
         <CharacterStyleRange AppliedCharacterStyle="CharacterStyle/$ID/[No character style]"/>
      </ParagraphStyleRange>
```

So, you can see, italic elements are in a separate tag, but without other content. Could you please suggest what I need to do?

Comment: That fragment of XSLT doesn't tell us much as to what goes wrong. Consider to post a minimal but complete stylesheet and the minimal but complete wrong output you get for that input sample you have shown. In general, although not knowing the exact result format needed for InDesign, it looks as if you could just write templates matching e.g. `li`, `li/i`, `li/span` or more generally `i` and `span`, creating any result element you want and using `<xsl:apply-templates/>` to keep up a recursive processing.

Comment: Thank you very much @Martin. I have updated my question with the latest code. As you can see, I got italic, but without other content.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to write templates mapping each element type to the corresponding result structure and inside use `<xsl:apply-templates/>` to keep processing up. So the basic approach for that sample would look like

```
<xsl:template match="li">
    <xsl:variable name="depth" select="count(ancestor::li) + 1"/>
    
    <xsl:variable name="listType">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="parent::ol">
          <xsl:value-of select="'NL'"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="'BL'"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    
     <ParagraphStyleRange AppliedParagraphStyle="ParagraphStyle/{$listType}{if ($depth eq 1) then '' else $depth}">
         <CharacterStyleRange AppliedCharacterStyle="CharacterStyle/$ID/[No character style]">
           <xsl:apply-templates/>
         </CharacterStyleRange>   
     </ParagraphStyleRange>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="i">
      <CharacterStyleRange AppliedCharacterStyle="CharacterStyle/Italic">
        <Content>      
           <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </Content>
    </CharacterStyleRange>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()[normalize-space()]">
    <Content>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </Content>
</xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93dFK9Q

That gives

```
<ParagraphStyleRange AppliedParagraphStyle="ParagraphStyle/BL">
   <CharacterStyleRange AppliedCharacterStyle="CharacterStyle/$ID/[No character style]">
      <Content>Systolic dysfunction: an </Content>
      <CharacterStyleRange AppliedCharacterStyle="CharacterStyle/Italic">
         <Content>
            <Content>inotropic</Content>
         </Content>
      </CharacterStyleRange>
      <Content> abnormality, due to myocardial infarction (MI) or dilated or ischemic cardiomyopathy (CM), resulting in diminished systolic emptying (ejection fraction &lt;45%).</Content>
   </CharacterStyleRange>
</ParagraphStyleRange>
```

I might not have captured all details of your needed output format but I hope the sample shows that the key is to use `apply-templates` to process child nodes with matching templates.